# Apache Virtual Server wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I am new to both Apache and wordpress. I am using Apache 2.2. I have mapped a public IP address to the server on which wordpress is located (192.168.0.99). From anywhere on the same net it is possible to type the public IP address into a browser and get the default Apache page, or type in [public IP address]/wordpress, and get the wordpress page I have set up.

When I attempt the same test from outside the network (e.g. using Safari on a Vodafone 3G), the public IP address brings up the default Apache page, but [public IP address]/wordpress refuses to load anything.

I have set up /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf as follows:

```
LogLevel debug

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/my_error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/my_custom_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

In MySQL,

```
wordpress.wp_options: option_id: 1,
option_name: siteurl,
option_value: http://192.168.0.99/wordpress,
autoload: yes
```

my_error_log and my_custom_log both receive sprays of messages, indicating that the Virtual host is gathering requests. When I try to access wordpress from the Vodafone mobile the only entry seen in my_custom_error is:

```
[Mobile network provider's IP] - - [Date and Time] "GET /wordpress/ HTTP/1.1" 200 99982
```

There are no entries in my_error_log.

What have I missed?

Comment: are you sure that your public IP port 80 is pointing to your 192.168.0.99 machine? If not check the forwarded ports in your router

Comment: The log message you show (probably from my_custom_log - typo in your question) indicates return status 200.  So as far as this log is concerned, it was properly processed.  Are you sure you did not receive anything?  In your browser, turn on developer mode (F12 in Chrome) and check the console.  View source will also show you if you did get something.  Worst case use fiddler to see what you received as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that wordpress expects to be hosted on the address that's set in the database.  If you happen to access it on a different address, wordpress will redirect you to the address in the database.  In your case, the public address will result in wordpress trying to serve the local address.

```
option_value: http://192.168.0.99/wordpress,
```

Solution 1: use a hostname. Set up a hostname to point to your public address and enter that as your wordpress's site address.

```
option_value: http://myhostname.somedomain.com/wordpress,
```

You can have the hostname point to the local address internally by using hosts file entries or setting up an internal DNS server with the local entry for your chosen hostname.  There are services such as [noip.com](https://www.noip.com) that will provide you with a hostname for free.

Solution 2: Another thing you could do, if you don't mind losing LAN access to the site, is to just update wordpress so that it's using the public rather than private ip address, and it should work as you expect from outside your network.